# Can anyone tell me what this is? Door frame swelling?

Tags: framing

[image]A Bulge appeared in door frame. [image]

Comment: If you just moved in I would think of a cheap fast repair to hide damage.  Can you post some more photos showing more of the door frame and one from the side?

Comment: We’ve been here about a year and this just showed up

Comment: You will need to pop/remove those paint bubbles anyway to fix, so open one up and see if the wood behind is wet/damp.

Comment: Looks like water damage.

Comment: What kind of water damage? Not next to a room with plumbing so not sure where anything would leak from

Comment: Well, if it isn't adjacent to any rooms with plumbing then perhaps a roof leak? Any rain?  You're going to have to diagnose it, we aren't there so we don't know the circumstances and with minimal information provided...it's a guessing game at best.

Comment: it looks rotten to me. does the flaw go inwards or  outwards?

Comment: You need to scrape the surface to see what is happening

Comment: scrape or cut in to inspect. could even be a pocket door cavity or other void covered by wall paper and then painted as a cheap fix/hide, and some air pressure differential caused it to pop out/in

Comment: Got any leaks above?